# DSolve gives 2 different solutions

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve below equation, but DSolve gives two different solutions an I don't know which one should I choose. Could anyone help me? My code is as below

```
DSolve[f'[r]/r + f''[r] == -A Exp[-B f[r]], f[r], r]
```

Boundary conditions are also known:

```
f'[R]= d
Integrate[r Exp[-B f[r]]= e,{r,0,R}]
```

Comment: What are the boundary conditions?

Comment: I know f'[r] in r=R and one other condition which is complicated @AccidentalFourierTransform

Comment: well, what is `f'[R]`?

Comment: a constant, say alpha @AccidentalFourierTransform

Comment: I would choose the first one, 'cause I'm too lazy to reach for the second. Now seriously: "_which one should I choose_" - for **what purpose**?

Comment: I have added the boundary. Does it help? @corey979

Comment: I have added both conditions @AccidentalFourierTransform

Comment: What do you mean by what purpose? My purpose is finding solution of this equation. It should only have one solution @corey979

Comment: @HolgerMate `x^2-1=0` It should only have one solution?

Comment: It is not a second order differential equation. @MariuszIwaniuk

Comment: There is uniqueness theory for 1st  order ODE's.  All second order ODE's can be converted to 1st order ODE. One of your 1st order ODE's is non-linear. You need to lookup uniqueness theory  for non-linear first order ODE's. It also depends on the interval of the solution.

Comment: In any case, if you want $f(r)$ to be well-behaved around $r=0$, you need to take `C[1] -> 0`.

Comment: The solution should be real and it sets c[1]=0 @AccidentalFourierTransform

Comment: r changes between $R$ and 0. @AccidentalFourierTransform

Comment: r changes between RR and 0. How can I use it to omit one solution?@Nasser